# What does it mean square brackets in the argoument of a function?

Tags: javascript

I found a description of the syntax of the JavaScript method reduce that is:

```
arr.reduce(callback(accumulator, currentValue[, index[, array]]) [, initialValue])
```

In this case for example what does the square breackets in the argument of this function mean?

Comment: It's optional parameters. Anything inside square brackets is not required.

Comment: Thanks you so much